# Apache Spark 2.0 MQTT - Err "No module named mqtt"

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, mqtt, importerror

I get this error when I try to run my application using spark 2.0. I tried downloading the package from https://github.com/spark-packages/dstream-mqtt but the repositories don't exist. Also, I tried searching for the packages at https://spark-packages.org/ , but couldn't find any. My program is very simple,

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from dstream_mqtt import MQTTUtils
#from pyspark.streaming.mqtt import MQTTUtils

sc = SparkContext()
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 6)

mqttStream = MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc,"tcp://192.168.4.54:1883","/test")
mqttStream.pprint()
mqttStream.saveAsTextFiles("test/status", "txt")


ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
ssc.stop()
```

I have downloaded and tried including the Jar files - spark-streaming-mqtt-assembly_2.11-1.6.2.jar and spark-streaming-mqtt_2.11-1.6.2.jar, but it is not helping.

The same code and packages just work fine with Spark 1.6.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Sisyphus, did you find solution for this? Because even I am facing similar issue.